# Llegar a una ruta en específico del servidor

Tags: codeigniter

Estoy trabajando con el framework **CodeIgniter** donde tengo una vista y en esa vista tengo esta parte de código donde traigo un audio **`.wav`**, hasta ahora todo funciona muy bien porque la carpeta donde tengo los audios está en el mismo framework como se dan cuenta.

Aquí traigo mi audio

```
<source src="<?= base_url()?>assets/grabaciones/<?php echo($archivowav);?>" 
        type="audio/wav">
```

**¿Cómo le hago para traer los audios que se encuentran en otros niveles remplazando la dirección que tengo yo?**

En este nivel está posicionada la página

> usuario:/var/www/DMG#

Pero los audios están en este nivel

> usuario:/media/externo/grabaciones#

**¿Cómo llego hasta los audios?**

Comment: ¿Has intentado crear un controlador que busque el archivo y te lo devuelva en lugar de tratar de acceder a el directamente desde la vista?
Eso te permitiría usar el File Helper (está en la documentación de CodeIgniter) o alguna función nativa de PHP que busque fuera de la estructura de directorios.